# Perl: file content into a scalar variable

Tags: perl, file, scalar

I am having problems doing this:

```
$contents = do { local $/;  <SEQ> };
$contents =~ "s/\n/ /g";
print $contents;
```

I want to join all lines of a file into one. However, it doesn't work...

Any idea what's happening with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#DESCRIPTION) module:

```
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;
my $text = read_file( 'filename' ) ;
$text =~ s/\n/ /g;
print $text;
```

If you don't want to use the module, you can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text;
open my $fh, "<", "./alarm.pl" or die $!;
{
    local $/;                   # enable localized slurp mode
    $text = <$fh>;
}
close $fh;

$text =~ s/\n/ /g;
print $text;
```

Answer (score 9):

remove the quote marks around the regexp

```
$contents = do { local $/;  <SEQ> };
$contents =~ s/\n/ /g;
print $contents;
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is probably [Perl6::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Perl6-Slurp-0.051003/lib/Perl6/Slurp.pm) module:

```
use Perl6::Slurp;
$contents = slurp \*SEQ;
```